# Need help figuring why there inst random characters appearing on every line

Tags: python

```
import os
import sys
import fileinput
import random
import string

stringLength=10
"""Generate a random string of fixed length """
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
Password = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

print ("Text to search for:")
textToSearch = input( "> " ) 

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = input( "> " )

tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    if textToSearch in line :
        print('Match Found')
    else:
        print('Match Not Found!!')
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, Password ) )
tempFile.close()

input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```

This is what happend:

```
start /min MinecraftClient.exe qQ47n2 - mc.cosmicmc.com

start /min MinecraftClient.exe qQ47n2 - mc.cosmicmc.com

start /min MinecraftClient.exe qQ47n2 - mc.cosmicmc.com
```

the qQ47n2 is what is changing
i want it to be random every line but as u can see it says qQ47n2 every line down ?

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you generate your password only once, outside of your `for` loop.

You could generate your password just before `tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, Password ) )`.

Comment: Enjoy your Minecraft game!